# NoMethodError when trying to autoload classes in Rails lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
# lib/devblog_extensions.rb
module DevblogExtensions
  class Time
    def self.random_date
      # implementation ...
    end
  end
end

# spec/factories/posts.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    release_date Time.random_date # NoMethodError occurs
  end
end
```

Then in `config/application.rb` I have:

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

But when I run `rspec` I still get a `NoMethodError`, so what am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: why are the paths so different? shouldn't your spec path be `spec/lib/devblog_extensions.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missing include

```
# spec/factories/posts.rb
include DevblogExtensions

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    release_date Time.random_date # NoMethodError occurs
  end
end
```

UPDATE: quick fix

```
# lib/devblog_extensions.rb
module DevblogExtensions
end

class Time
  def self.random_date
    Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: Still get `NoMethodError`, plus I thought autoloading it in `config/application.rb` would make it available across the entire app without needing to use `include`?

Comment: This works, but I feel a little uneasy about it.  Fyi, add an initializer .rb file in `config/initializers` and simply `require` the module in that initializer.  That way, you don't have to `include` at the top of files.